# Return variable name which satisfies condition on numeric variables only

Tags: r, conditional-statements, apply, sapply

I am trying to create a new variable in my dataframe which returns the variable name for which a condition is satisfied, however I also have a chr variable on the dataset so some sort of numeric wrapper would have to be applied.

Dataset before:

```
          ChrV   |   V1  |   V2  |   V3       
 Obs 1 |  chr1   |  0.65 |  0.30 |  0.40
 Obs 2 |  chr2   |  0.35 |  0.75 |  0.42
 Obs 3 |  chr3   |  0.10 |  0.43 |  0.80
```

My Solution:

- Save chr variable.

  ```
  ChrV <- ds$ChrV
  ```
- Delete chr variable off the dataset (alternative to numeric wrapper)

  ```
  ds$ChrV <- NULL
  ```
- Create new column - apply across all rows of the dataset: function - paste the column names for which the absolute value of x is greater of equal to 0.5.

  ```
  ds$V4 <- apply(ds, 1, function(x) paste(names(which(abs(x) >= 0.5))))
  ```
- Bind chr variable back to the dataset.

  ```
  ds <- cbind(ChrV, ds)
  ```

Output:

```
          ChrV   |   V1  |   V2  |   V2  |   V4       
 Obs 1 |  chr1   |  0.65 |  0.30 |  0.40 |  Var 1
 Obs 2 |  chr2   |  0.35 |  0.75 |  0.42 |  Var 2
 Obs 3 |  chr3   |  0.10 |  0.43 |  0.80 |  Var 3
```

My Problem:

While my solution works, I need to find a more elegant solution that ignores the chr variable, (so it only considers the numeric variables and I don't need to remove the variables and bind them again later), and that is also applicable to any dataset regardless of the amount of columns and rows.

> dput(ds)

```
structure(list(
ChrV = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), 
V1 = c(3, 2, 1), 
V2 = c(1, 3, 2), 
V3 = c(1, 2, 3)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
 .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002541ef0>)
```

Comment: Do you want index of maximum value in each row? `max.col(df[2:4])` ?

Comment: @RonakShah no, specifically absolute values which are greater of equal to 0.5

Comment: @Seni What is the expected output if there are more then one value > | 0.5 | per row?

Comment: @markus that shouldn't happen but if it does, then NA

Answer (score 1):

If `tidyverse` solution is acceptable you can do it as following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(cname, val, V1:V3) %>%
  group_by(ChrV) %>%
  mutate(V4 = cname[abs(as.numeric(val)) >= .5] %>% str_c(collapse = ' ')) %>%
  spread(cname, val)
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns - Error: Column `ChrV` is unknown

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the data frame in the apply function:

```
ds$V4 <- apply(ds[colnames(ds) != "ChrV"], 1, function(x) 
paste(names(which(abs(x) >= 0.5))))
```

**EDIT**

For class data.frame, removing paste and subsetting the output of apply:

```
> ds <- data.frame(
+   ChrV = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), 
+   V1 = c(3, 2, 1), 
+   V2 = c(1, 3, 2), 
+   V3 = c(1, 2, 3))
> 
> 
> ds$V4 <- apply(ds[colnames(ds) != "ChrV"], 1, function(x) {
+   names(which(abs(x) >= 0.5))
+ })[,1]
> 
> ds
  ChrV V1 V2 V3 V4
1 chr1  3  1  1 V1
2 chr2  2  3  2 V2
3 chr3  1  2  3 V3
>
```

Bye!

Comment: Thanks but it returns - Error in `[.data.table`(ds, colnames(ds) != "ChrV") : i evaluates to a logical vector length 5 but there are 6 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.

Comment: First it must be transformed to data.frame(). Now I'm in my cellphone. I will edit in short.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it with `max.col`

```
ds$V4 <- paste("Var", max.col(abs(ds[2:4]) > 0.5))

df
#     ChrV   V1   V2   V3    V4
#Obs1 chr1 0.65 0.30 0.40 Var 1
#Obs2 chr2 0.35 0.75 0.42 Var 2
#Obs3 chr3 0.10 0.43 0.80 Var 3
```

Or if you want the column names

```
ds$V4 <- names(ds)[2:4][max.col(abs(ds[2:4]) > 0.5)]
```

---

If you want to dynamic way to select only numeric columns , we can use `Filter` as suggested by @markus

```
new_ds <- Filter(is.numeric, ds)
ds$V4 <- names(new_ds)[max.col(abs(new_ds) > 0.5)]
```